# How can I enable brotli compression for my NodeJS app built with express?

Tags: node.js, express, http-compression, brotli

I would like to use Brotli compression for my node application built on express. I deliver content (HTML, CSS and JS) with `app.use(express.static('public'))`.

I have found the `shrink-ray` module which does Brotli compression perfectly. However, when I install it and run the `nsp check` from the node security platform module, I get security vulnerabilities, which makes it impossible to use in my project.

Does anyone know a good alternative to enable Brotli compression on a node app using express? I´ve tried `express-static-gzip` but didn´t manage to make it work, it was still gzipped even on a simple tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried `enableBrotli` option in  `express-static-gzip` ?

Comment: Yes, but it was still gzip compression with no size reduction

Comment: `enableBrotli` option only works if you have the brotli file already available. 
You can read this article to learn how to use use that option.
https://codeburst.io/express-brotli-webpack-a60773e7ec6c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new `shrink-ray-current` module is an alternative that works with updated dependencies.